# Neo4J windows installation

Tags: neo4j

Downloaded Neo4j community version, the file named "neo4j-desktop-offline-1.1.13-setup.exe". Running the binary successfully installed. Launching the application takes me to configuration of database location "Please choose path where you want to store application data" and regardless of what path i choose, clicking "Confirm" does not do anything at all and it remains on the same screen. 
Am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same problem. I fixed it by adding a new PATH in environmental variables,

`Advanced System Settings` > `Environment Variable` > `system variable` > `path` > `new`: `C:\Windows\System32\wbem`

After setting, reopen the Neo4j application and it will allow you a select the path where you want to save application data.

REASON

In the developer console, you will see the following error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Command failed: wmic logicaldisk get
>   size,freespace,caption 'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

The actual WMIC binary is located at `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe` you need to set the path if it is not yet defined.

Answer (score 0):

try opening http://127.0.0.1:7477 or http://localhost:7474 in your browser

Comment: Thanks, tried both with and without ssl, nothing listening there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Windows 7, and after trying the solutions others have suggested around fixing the Path environment variable to no avail, I found upgrading PowerShell solved the problem. To do this, I upgraded my Windows Management Framework (to 5.1 at the time of this writing) by following the appropriate link for my version of Windows from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell

For Windows 7, I retrieved Win7AndW2K8R2-KB3191566-x64.zip from the Download link found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616.

I unzipped and installed it, and after a reboot it worked (for Neo4j Desktop 1.4.15). Upgrades to WMF for other versions of Windows are on the same page.