# Please choose path where you want to store application data in neo4j after installation problem

Tags: neo4j, path, confirm

After installing the neo4j desktop 1.1.14-1.1.17 it does not confirm the path.

[image]

Comment: There is [another question similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54223764/neo4j-windows-installation), without a good answer. You may want to create a new [neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues) about this.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to your env variables PATH=%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem

Answer (score 2):

If You have set env variables `PATH=%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem` and it is not working,

please set the path for Powershell

```
PATH=%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

I was facing the same problem and was able to fix it with this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Some organisations might have powershell diabled by administrators. Please check if you are able to launch powershell. if you can, navigate to the instalation folder of neo4j and launch it from comand by execuiting  & '.\Neo4j Desktop.exe'

Comment: if you dont have powershel you can download it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on Win10 following this approach (including debug steps so you can check if your issue is the same):

- checked the error logs under Developer>Show error log

> ```
> Get-CimInstance : Ungültige Klasse
> In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
> + Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk:String) [Get-CimInstance], CimException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041010,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.GetCimInstanceCommand
> ```

=> This error told me that Neo4J start procedure fails on this windows cmd:

> Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalDisk

- open PowerShell as admin
- test the command there and received the same error
- I checked the winmgmt repo but it stated its consistent

> ```
> PS C:\Windows\system32> winmgmt /verifyrepository 
> Das WMI-Repository ist konsistent.
> ```

- I dared to reset the winmgmt repo

> ```
> winmgmt /resetrepository
> ```

- then the Get-CmiInstance command worked again
- And after restarting Neo4J Desktop the [Confirm] button worked.

Hope this helps, cause its 2023 and the Neo4J Desktop Setup is still stumbling on this.

BR Adrian

Answer (score -1):

To path in environment variable add C:\windows\system32\wbem

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and tried everything as check PATH variable, update powershell, update Java, made an JAVA_HOME variable and in the end it turned out that the problem was that my antivirus was blocking powershell. And now it works